# If two signals are disjoint in the frequency domain, are they uncorralated?

Tags: signal-processing

If two signals are disjoint in the frequency domain, are they uncorralated?

I think that I am not understanding the frequency domain concept :(

Comment: I'm not an expert, can you show an example of what you mean? Or tell us what kind of disjoint signals you are talking about, such as W-disjoint orthogonal signals? Also, there are different measures of correlation, which one are you referring to? cross-correlation?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If there is no spectral overlap, then the signals are wholly uncorrelated. Correlation is a type of convolution, which is means that you are multiplying the spectrums of the two signals together. Since there is no overlap in the frequency domain, their product will always be zero.